# Can I access the Assembly GUID from my webconfig file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a GUID in my assembly information that is auto created when the project is created.
The current system requires a matching GUID on the database so it can identify the solution.

(Yeah, it's VB.net)

```
 <Assembly: Guid("43aca7cb-9360-4642-adc5-6d29b4732bed")>
```

What I'm doing is manually copying this GUID into the webconfig as a Setting for the solution, which adds it to the Settings.Designer.vb file.

Ala

```
  <setting name="ApplicationId" serializeAs="String">
    <value>43aca7cb-9360-4642-adc5-6d29b4732bed</value>
  </setting>
```

From there it get's passed on to the database or wherever. It's not much hassle to do this, and the GUID shouldn't ever change, but I can't help but think it would be tidier if I didn't have to copy the GUID string in each Solution, but had something that referenced the Assembly value directly.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 var assemblyName = "System"; // assembly to get the guid

 var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == assemblyName);

 var attr = assembly
        .GetCustomAttributes(false)
        .OfType<GuidAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

 var guid = attr.Value;
```

But IMO seems better to keep the guid in the web.config, because it is  "hard coded" there.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it would be possible to do in code behind, so it looks like you can't just include something like <value>[Assembly.Guid]</value> in the webconfig

Comment: For that you can add the assembly name in the appsetings in web.config, then when at runtime you could use the code above to read the guid from the desired assembly. There is no way to do [assembly.guid], you'll have to write some code if you want something to work in some particular way.